# Cannot load system environment variables when spring boot JAR is run as service

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a simple spring boot application that returns value of a system env variable

application.properties

`my-var=${SYSTEM_ENV_VAR}`

where `SYSTEM_ENV_VAR` is a system variable defined in `/etc/environment`

DemoApp.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Value("${my-var}")
    String env;

    @GetMapping(path = "/")
    public String get() {
        return "This: " + env;
    }
}
```

I follow the process of creating an executable jar with `mvn clean package`

Now, when I execute the jar as `/home/ubuntu/sample-app/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, I get the correct value of my  system environment variable

I created a service

/etc/systemd/system/demoapp.service

```
[Unit]
Description=desc
After=syslog.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/environment
User=root    
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/sample-app/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I execute the service as `sudo systemctl start demoapp.service`.

When I check the status `sudo systemctl status demoapp.service`, I see an error trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 
'SYSTEM_ENV_VAR' in value "${SYSTEM_ENV_VAR}"
```

But I know that `/etc/environment` is loading since I can see other entries in the log which show the loading of all my system envs

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So this is what I ended up doing.

I noticed that removing the `export` keyword in my `/etc/environment` resulted in the value of `SYSTEM_ENV_VAR` being interpreted and displayed.

But now apache started complaining since it could not find the value for `SYSTEM_ENV_VAR`. Therefore, I split the declaration into 2 parts. So the file looks like:

/etc/environment

```
export SYSTEM_ENV_VAR
SYSTEM_ENV_VAR=the-value
```

This way, apache and spring boot both are happy.

Answer (score 1):

Value that you are using for ${my-var} should not be ${SYSTEM_ENV_VAR} instead should be the actual path to the system variable. 
So your application.properties should have

`my-var=path/to/system/variable`

and not

`my-var=${SYSTEM_ENV_VAR}`

Comment: When I add `my-var=/etc/env/SYSTEM_ENV_VAR`, it runs fine when I execute JAR directly and displays the value of `SYSTEM_ENV_VAR`. But when I run it as a service, it displays /etc/env/SYSTEM_ENV_VAR and not the value